# Fluent nHibernate - how to select DISTINCT dates without time?

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

let's say I have a column (datetime) with the following values:

```
2015-05-16 20:17:05.033
2015-05-16 20:29:07.130
2015-05-17 01:01:04.690
2015-05-17 01:02:28.053
2015-05-17 11:24:37.667
2015-05-17 11:25:24.913
```

How can I select the distinct list to the `DateTime list` to

```
2015-05-16
2015-05-17
```

?

In plain SQL, I can just do `DISTINCT CONVERT(date, myDateColumn)` but how can I do this in Fluent nHibernate ?

Comment: *Fluent* nhibernate is just for mapping your class definitions to database tables, it doesn't add any querying capabilities. What technology are you using to query? QueryOver? LINQ? HQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `distinct` requirement makes this a bit more complicated, but NHibernate already has various date/time methods registered for use in Criteria and QueryOver queries. This is slightly different than the SQL you asked for, but the results should be the same:

```
var distinctDates = session.QueryOver<MyTable>()
    .Select(Projections.Distinct(
        Projections.SqlFunction("date", NHibernateUtil.Date,
            Projections.Property<MyTable>(mt => mt.DateCreated))))
    .List<DateTime>();
```

This will generate the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT
    distinct dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, this_.DateCreated)) as y0_
FROM
    MyTable this_
```

Without the `distinct` requirement, you could do the following:

```
session.QueryOver<MyTable>()
    .Select(mt => mt.DateCreated.Date)
    .List<DateTime>()
    .Dump();
```

Inside of a QueryOver expression, NHibernate "knows" how to translate accessing the `Date` property into the correct SQL.